# SSLCertVerificationError при запросах через aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, python-3.8, aiohttp

При попытке совершить любой банальный запрос через aiohttp выхожу на ошибку

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host habr.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '178.248.237.68'. (_ssl.c:1108)")]
```

сам код:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://habr.com/ru/post/337420') as response:
            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

            html = await response.text()
            print("Body:", html[:15], "...")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Через `requests` всё прекрасно работает, ошибка возникает исключительно при асинхронных запросах.

```
ubuntu 20.04
Python 3.8.2
aiogram==2.10.1
aiohttp==3.7.0
aiohttp-proxy==0.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==20.2.0
Babel==2.8.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
multidict==5.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.14.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.11
yarl==1.6.2
aiogram==2.10.1
aiohttp==3.7.0
aiohttp-proxy==0.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==20.2.0
Babel==2.8.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
multidict==5.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.14.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.11
yarl==1.6.2aiogram==2.10.1
aiohttp==3.7.0
aiohttp-proxy==0.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==20.2.0
Babel==2.8.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
multidict==5.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.14.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.11
yarl==1.6.2
ubuntu 20.04
aiogram==2.10.1
aiohttp==3.7.0
aiohttp-proxy==0.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==20.2.0
Babel==2.8.0
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.10
multidict==5.0.0
pkg-resources==0.0.0
python-dotenv==0.14.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.25.11
yarl==1.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена установкой aiohttp==3.7.1 Асинхронные бибы этого семейства на данный момент плохо работают с питоном 3.8 Если у вас подобная проблема - просто вручную поставьте самую новую версию с гитхаба